# sharepoint calendar messing up accessibility mode tab order

Tags: asp.net, html, sharepoint, calendar, web-parts

on any OOB sharepoint page, if you "tab" through the page, the first tab brings up a "turn on more accessible mode" menu item.  that is, except for a page with a calendar web part.  Once you tab off the browser menu, the first tab item becomes the calendar web part, skipping over the menu item and all other content.

I've tried setting tab index to -1, 0, 1 on the div with the menu that I want hit first, but the calendar web part still gets the first tab, forcing users who tab through pages to have to cycle through all controls to get to the "accessible mode" menu.

Any ideas what else I could do to make sure this loads as the first item tabbed to, no matter what?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

try using JQuery, to remove (or edit) the tabindex of the table holding the calendar webpart. It probably has a tabindex 0 , that occurs later in the code then the accessible mode div, and the browser will see 2 items with tabindex 0, the startindex (-1 doesn't work) for the tab button. Seeing 2 items, it will use the last item found in the html as the start for the tab button.